# I am trying to find all real x satisfying the equation log(1-x) = log(1+x).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find all real $x$ satisfying the equation $\log(1-x) = \log(1+x)$. I have tried raising both sides with $e$, but I am having a hard time proving my results. Any hints? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you "tried raising both sides with e" then you should have gotten $1-x = 1+x$, which has only one solution, namely $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log$ is a one-to-one function.  Therefore $\log(1-x)=\log(1+x)$ only if $1-x=1+x$.  So take
$$
1-x = 1+x
$$
and add $x$ to both sides, and subtract $1$ from both sides.  The rest is simple.

Comment: "The rest" is just symbols "x", "=", and "0" in that order.

Comment: @djechlin : Not quite.  It says $0 = 2x$.  Then you have to divide both sides by $2$, so that division is "the rest". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are struggling with the raising both sides with $e$-part, so let me show you. You start out with:
$$\log(1-x) = \log(1+x).$$
Raising $e$ to both sides gives you
$$e^{\log(1-x)} = e^{\log(1+x)}.$$
Now, the $e$ and the $\log$ cancel each other: It is true that $e^{\log(a)} = a$ for all positive $a$. So I get $e^{\log(1-x)} = 1-x$, and $e^{\log(1+x)} = 1+x$. This means that my equation becomes
$$1-x = 1+x.$$
You can probably take it from here.

Comment: On a side note, $e^{\log a}=a$ for all real $a$.

Comment: @Brody Either you mean $\log(e^a) = a$ for all real $a$, or otherwise you are thinking of complex numbers.

Comment: No, I meant $\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R},\,e^{\log a}=a$. I implicitly assumed a certain constraint, so ignore this remark.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that we need $1-x>0$ and $1+x>0$, i.e. $-1 < x < 1$.

Applying the standard "[laws of logs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=laws%20of%20logs&tbm=isch&imgil=Ki0T0vLCI1zpYM%253A%253B1xhX5i6w_INTzM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmathsathawthorn.pbworks.com%25252Fw%25252Fpage%25252F20555379%25252FC2%2525252520LAWS%2525252520OF%2525252520LOGARITHMS&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Ki0T0vLCI1zpYM%253A%252C1xhX5i6w_INTzM%252C_&biw=1600&bih=785&usg=__m-_z4nMgBPEZxxDpkuQizeZQt78%3D&ved=0ahUKEwil4K39soLKAhVEJnIKHcL9CNsQyjcIMg&ei=uC6DVqWkMcTMyAPC-6PYDQ#imgrc=Ki0T0vLCI1zpYM%3A&usg=__m-_z4nMgBPEZxxDpkuQizeZQt78%3D)" we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(1-x)&=&\ln(1+x) \\ \\
\ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x) &=& 0 \\ \\
\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) &=& 0 \\ \\
\frac{1-x}{1+x} &=& \mathrm{e}^0 \\ \\
\frac{1-x}{1+x} &=& 1 \\ \\
1-x &=& 1+x \\ \\
-2x &=& 0 \\ \\ 
x &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $\log(1-x)$ is defined for all $1-x>0\iff x<1$ &

$\log(1+x)$ is defined for all $1+x>0\iff x>-1$

hence, equality will hold for all real $x$ such that $$-1<x<1$$

since, logarithm is one-to-one function hence we can compare the numbers on the same base on both the sides 
$$\log(1-x)=\log(1+x)$$ 
$$\iff 1-x=1+x$$
$$2x=0$$$$ x=\color{red}{0}$$
Obviously the above value $x=0$ satisfy $-1<x<1$ hence $x=0$ is the solution